# Check only last 3 digits of sensor output

Tags: c

I have a library from WiringPi for DHT11 sensor and I need to modify condition which checks if the value read from sensor is good.

Sometimes the library reads bad values which are 255.255,255.255 or 55,255.255 etc.

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBOOt.png)

There is the condition in the library:

```
if(counter==255)
        break;
```

But it doesn't work if the value is e.g. 55,255.255

How can I modify this condition the check last 3 digits of output?
If the output is wrong, there are always "255" at the end of value.
I tried to add conditions like

```
if(counter==255)
        break;
        else if(counter==255.255)
        break;
```

But it doesn't solve all possible situations and I realy don't know anything about C/C++

Here is the whole library:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAX_TIME 85
#define DHT11PIN 7
#define ATTEMPTS 5
int dht11_val[5]={0,0,0,0,0};

int dht11_read_val()
{
  uint8_t lststate=HIGH;
  uint8_t counter=0;
  uint8_t j=0,i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     dht11_val[i]=0;
  pinMode(DHT11PIN,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DHT11PIN,LOW);
  delay(18);
  digitalWrite(DHT11PIN,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(40);
  pinMode(DHT11PIN,INPUT);
  for(i=0;i<MAX_TIME;i++)
  {
    counter=0;
    while(digitalRead(DHT11PIN)==lststate){
      counter++;
      delayMicroseconds(1);
      if(counter==255)
        break;
    }
    lststate=digitalRead(DHT11PIN);
    if(counter==255)
       break;
    // top 3 transistions are ignored
    if((i>=4)&&(i%2==0)){
      dht11_val[j/8]<<=1;
      if(counter>16)
        dht11_val[j/8]|=1;
      j++;
    }
  }
  // verify checksum and print the verified data
  if((j>=40)&&(dht11_val[4]==((dht11_val[0]+dht11_val[1]+dht11_val[2]+dht11_val[3])& 0xFF)))
  {
    printf("%d.%d,%d.%d\n",dht11_val[0],dht11_val[1],dht11_val[2],dht11_val[3]);
    return 1;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  int attempts=ATTEMPTS;
  if(wiringPiSetup()==-1)
    exit(1);
  while(attempts)
  {
    int success = dht11_read_val();
    if (success) {
      break;
    }
    attempts--;
    delay(500);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The counter is uint8, it will never contain a `255.255`.

Comment: I recommend you learn C and not overlook, the C++  tag is unnecessary.

Comment: @Yunnosch - please take a look at the screen I added

Comment: I did, thanks for confirming my assumption.

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of pure text. If your output is text, copy&paste the text into your question. That's no artwork which requires images

Answer (score 0):

No single variable in your code can hold "255.255", that would require a string or a float. You are obviously referring to the output of
`printf("%d.%d,%d.%d\n",dht11_val[0],dht11_val[1],dht11_val[2],dht11_val[3]);`.

This printf can never produce a three-value output like `55,255.255`.
I assume that your output would be `55.255,255.255`.
This in turn means that in case of error you will find the "last three digits" in dht11_val[3].

If my assumption is not correct please provide much more detail on the error circumstances.

On the other hand, I suspect that looking for that value is not the solution for your problem either. The function is more complicated. The value of 255 seems the result of an endless loop which is detected by breaking early at counter = 255. So I am pretty sure that checking "the last three digits" is a LESS precise check than what is already implemented.